# Configuring bridged network connection --- Windows 7 host, Ubuntu 10.04 guest --- VMWare Workstation 8

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu-10.04, vmware

Here is my IPCONFIG /ALL from the host (Windows 7 64-bit):

[image]

Here is my IFCONFIG from the guest (Ubuntu 10.04):

[image]

To be honest, I don't have experience configuring a network between a host and a guest in VMWare (a virtual machine). I've searched high and low on the internet, but I haven't seen anything that can help. Perhaps I'm just not using the right keywords when I search. Nevertheless, does anyone here have any experience with establishing a network connection?

Edit: One important note. I don't use DHCP to provide private addresses to the hosts on my LAN. I use "static" IP addresses on my internal network by configuring each IP address manually in the host's network configuration utility (I have TV's, XBOX 360, and a few PC's). I would like to configure the IP on the virtual machine guest manually as well. The reason is because my XBOX 360 only works properly using a static IP address. It will kick me off XBOX Live if it has one given by the router (via DHCP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a static IP requires a bit of work. There are many different ways to do it. I will teach you first the *graphical* way to do it, but you will see that it is **much easier** to do it with commands from a terminal.

First, you can do it graphically. In the upper right corner, you have the icon of the *Network Manager*: since you are disconnected, it looks like an empty slice of pie. Right click on it, go to *Edit Connections*, choose *Wired Connection*, then click on *Wired Connection 1*, choose *Edit*; *IPv4 Settings*. Here choose, for *Method*, *Manual*; then click on *Add*, and type in: 192.168.1.171 for your address, and 255.255.255.0 for your mask. Then click on DNSs servers, and write: 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8. Lastly, click on *Routes*, *Gateway*,and put 192.168.1.1 in the Address part. Save everything, and test your connection.

You can also do it from a terminal. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
First, it is most convenient to become superuser:

```
   sudo su
```

and then provide your password at the prompt. Then you will have to give these commands:

```
   service network-manager stop
   ifconfig eth0 down
   ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.171 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
   route add default gw 192.168.1.1
   echo 8.8.4.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf
   echo 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
   exit
```

This is it. The first command stops the network manager, the second and third initialize your network interface giving it the IP address 192.168.1.171, the fourth command tells your pc how to route internet requests, the fifth and sixth command establish the DNSs. The last command makes you leave the su (=superuser) state.

If you want to do it every time you start your Ubuntu VM, you create a file in your home directory, */home/your_name*, let's call it my_internet.sh, where you put all of the above commands, **preceded** by this line

```
   #!/bin/sh
```

You save the file, then issue this command

```
   chmod 755 my_internet.sh
```

then, as sudo, you edit the file /etc/rc.local, and put the following line

```
   /home/your_name/my_internet.sh
```

in the *next to the last* line, leaving *exit 0* as the last line. Done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do a bridged connection, then really all you have to do is configure the guest with a static IP address as if it was a real network card on a real PC. The point of bridged networking is that your guest appears like another PC on your network. So, look up how to configure a static IP on Ubuntu 10.04.